# Apresentação da consulta php

Tags: php, sql, query

Preciso que me ajudem a criar uma função em php que liste várias tabelas em uma linha com várias colunas, dependendo da quantidade de registros na base de dados e do espaçamento das tabelas definido pela `<div class="span">`

Essa é a minha função, mas ela está apenas listando em várias linhas com uma única coluna:

```
<?php
require 'conexao.php';
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'select * from homem_classic');
?>
<?php $titulo ="Homem Clássico";
include 'includes/header.php';
include 'includes/footer.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-PT">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
<div class="imagens">
<table class="tabela">

<?php while ($product=mysqli_fetch_object($result)) { ?>

<tr>
    <td><img src="<?php echo $product->imagem; ?>" alt=""></td>
</tr>       
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $product->nome; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $product->descricao; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>    
<p><a class="btn btn-info" href="cart.php?id=<?php echo $product->id; ?>"><?php echo $product->preco; ?><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a></p>
    </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Coloque a parte php também, como vai buscar os dados?

Answer (score 6):

Uma [tabela](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) é criada utilizando `TR` para abrir linhas e `TD` para abrir celulas.

Uma `TR` com múltiplas `TD` é o que pretendes:

```php
<?php
while ($product=mysqli_fetch_object($result)) { ?>

<tr>
  <td><img src="<?php echo $product->imagem; ?>" alt=""></td>
  <td><?php echo $product->nome; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $product->descricao; ?></td>
  <td><p><a class="btn btn-info" href="cart.php?id=<?php echo $product->id; ?>"><?php echo $product->preco; ?><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a></p></td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>
```

**Exemplo tabelas:**

```html
<h4>Linha com uma células</h4>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>João</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Azul</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Joana</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rosa</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h4>Linha com múltiplas células</h4>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>João</td>
    <td>Azul</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Joana</td>
    <td>Rosa</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Le @Zuul is back!